# httr disable "Expect: 100-continue"

Tags: r

I am trying to send a json to [bosun](http://bosun.org/) in R with `httr::POST`.

The `set_config(verbose())` is enabled and I saw the header: `Expect: 100-continue` which might trigger a bug of jetty.

The command is:

```
response <- httr::POST(url = "http://192.168.65.1:8070/api/put?details", 
                     body = json_str, 
                     add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"))
```

The verbose shows:

```
-> POST http://192.168.65.1:8070/api/put?details HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0 Rcurl/1.96.0 httr/0.6.0
-> Host: 192.168.65.1:8070
-> Accept: */*
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip
-> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
-> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
-> Content-Length: 1
-> Expect: 100-continue
```

How should I disable the header `Expect: 100-continue`?

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C        
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C           
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RJSONIO_1.3-0 httr_0.6.0    RCurl_1.96-0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6  stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: When I test with http://requestb.in/, i don't actually see that header being sent. Are you sure it's actually there in the message and causing you trouble? I'd be more worried that your content-length appears to be 1 -- seems kind of small. If you need to make sure it's not set, just add `add_headers("Expect"="")` to your POST call.

Comment: Your suggestion works! Thanks.

Comment: Note that the content-length is 1 because it is a test string. The server should return an error of parsing json instead of invalid request. After using your suggestion, the issue is resolved.

Comment: If you would like someone who commented your post to get notification, use the following feature: @MrFlick. Otherwise he won't know you responded since it's not his post.

Comment: @BondedDust Nope, I did not receive any. AFAIK you only get one if it's your post or you are mentioned via @: [link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/). Please delete this after you read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the Expect header, you just set it to an empty string. Add

```
add_headers("Expect"="")
```

To your `POST` call

Comment: I would have expected that to fail parsing and to need to be either`"Expect\"=\""` or `'Expect"="'`

Comment: It's just basic named parameter syntax. I think you can do `add_headers(Expect="")`

Comment: Ah, I see, now. The dbl-quotes are matched. Funny how one's brain can see sequences differently. I forgot that the names in function calls can be quoted. Does this also work: `add_headers(Expect="")` ?